# Importing projects

Tags: android, onclick, listener

I had many Android projects that were working fine in my old pc. now, when I tried to re import them, they are not running. Problem is that `onClickListener` is not working. Wherever there is `onClick method`, it throws an Error:

```
The method onClick(View) of type new View.OnClickListener(){} must override a superclass method
```

My actual method is :

```
myBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
        @Override  
        public void onClick(View v) {  
           //my code  
        }  
    });
```

What would be the problem?In every project wherever there is `onClick` method it shows the same.

Comment: have you tried cleaning and rebuilding all projects? also you can try fixing project properties of each projects. for that,right click on a project>Android Tools>Fix Project Properties

Comment: Please remove all imports and try again. Are you write the onClick() or it is automatically added into code by writing "button." check all imports first. If this will not used for you then set sdk path again and again download new software from Help menu.

Comment: Its not in one project to remove import statements. There are many projects. Is there any other method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using my supehuman guessing powers I assume that you are using eclipse.  Eclipse projects  are not portable between machines as they contain absolute paths ( but that does not stop developers from checking them in into source control system ).

Your options are:

- recreate eclipse project from sources
- create maven build with android plugin and make it create you an fresh eclipse project
- spring 150 bucks and buy you license for IntelliJ IDEA ( or just use free community edition which also has android plugins )

Comment: check java source version setting -  @Override came later

Answer (score 0):

simply remove all `@Override` annotation above the `onClick()` methods

Comment: but its an overridden method? how can i do that?

Comment: if you remove the annotation  and you wrote the function header correctly it will override it ..

Answer (score 0):

Goto project menu and clean the project.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Simply remove all @Override

Option 2: In **Eclipse** -> **Window** -> **Preferences** -> **Java** -> **Compiler**, set "Compiler compliance level" to 1.6 or higher.